# Android App crashes when "@babel/preset-env" is added

Tags: react-native, babel-jest

While running:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android
```

My app crashes at the end of the build without any log.

The problem is coming from `@babel/preset-env` in `babel.config.js` (used by jest tests)

`babel.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', "@babel/preset-env", '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ],
};
```

Removing `"@babel/preset-env"` is resolving the issue, but I need it to launch Jest.

Do you have any idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by simply removing `'@babel/preset-react'` and `'@babel/preset-env'` from `babel.config.js`.

Code was transpiling with `module:metro-react-native-babel-preset` which caused this issue.